# Could not obtain grant code: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect, keycloak, express-session

I'm trying to access protected by Keycloak url - *`/hello`* in the browser.
The url is served by the node.js app
This error is thrown by the [following code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/54815e742a931fe6f750a4a024c37ccc4d4fdc43/middleware/post-auth.js#L53):

after the following sequence of actions:

1) adding client and user to keycloak to KeyCloak master realm

2) protecting express node.js app's url:

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let kcConfig = { 
    clientId: 'test_ui',
    // secret : "d31c4718-12e9-407b-9bf2-cb72734a23f0", 
    public: true,
    serverUrl: https://127.0.0.1/auth,
    resource: "test_ui",
    realm: 'master'
}
var session = require('express-session');
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

var keycloak = new Keycloak(  {store : memoryStore},  kcConfig);

this.app.use(session({
    secret: 'mySecret',
    // resave: false,
    // saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore
  }));

this.app.use( keycloak.middleware() );
this.app.get( '/hello', keycloak.protect());
```

3) accessing the protected url in the browser, being redirected to Keycloak login screen, authenticating... then ther error is popped.

The following sequence of requests is seen in the wireshark:

```
/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=test_ui&state=504b250d-8616-4685-8c8d-5032713c883a&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1/hello/auth_callback&scope=openid&response_type=code
```

after the authentication in login screen:

```
/auth/realms/master/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=TwhsWxUig85PFHfiv-31OTHQl3aApD6z0lMdOr8hgDc&execution=d58a2cad-2be2-4797-b35a-d7b606945b14&client_id=test_ui&tab_id=ywQfz51qnM0
```

I thought about adding `sslRequired: "none"` to `kcConfig`, but doing 
seems to have no effect.
Tried to use also confidential client instead of the public one to no avail.

*package.json* contents:

```
"express": "4.16.2",
"keycloak-connect" : "4.3.0",
"express-session" : "1.15.6"
```

Keycloak 4.3 is used.

What is the cause of the issue and how to fix this error?

**Update**

Added `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";`
to *node.js* app following [response](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-April/013667.html) in Keycloak mailing list and now getting error:

> Could not obtain grant code: 401:Unauthorized

Comment: `Could not obtain grant code: 401:Unauthorized` - me too :/

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the referenced mailing list:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
```

works like a charm.